# Every x days vs every xth day of the month

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following cron expression:

```
0 0 */30 * *
```

How come it still runs every 30th day of the month and not every 30 days starting from now? Having the expression:

```
0 0 30 * *
```

Yields the same run times:

```
2013-07-30 00:00:00
2013-08-30 00:00:00
2013-09-30 00:00:00
2013-10-30 00:00:00
2013-11-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: What do you mean "every 30 days that start on this day"? If the month were 60+ days long, the first would run on day 60 but the second wouldn't.

Comment: You might want to research `anacron` or other schedulers that are a little more advanced than basic `cron`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use `at` instead of cron.  You can use `at` to schedule your script to run 30 days from now with the following:
    at now +30 day  /path/to/your/script

Then, just put the same line near the end of your script, to schedule it to run again 30 days later.